# c# аналог java wildcard

Tags: java, c#

Переписываю код с java на .net c# столкнулся с проблемой переноса классов с wildcard. Есть два класса

```
public abstract class Client<T extends Connection<?>>
public class Connection<T extends Client<?>>
```

я думал, что можно сделать вот так

```
public abstract class Client<T> where Connection<U>
```

но оказалось, что даже вот так не работает

```
public abstract class Client<T, U> where Connection<T, U>
public abstract class Connection<T, U> where Client<T, U>
```

так как же выйти из ситуации ?

Comment: например это не работает потому что [ограничения неверно накладываются](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)

Comment: Прямо перенести то, что вы говорите, не получится. Но вопрос в том, какой _смысл_ вы хотите получить? Опишите, чего именно (какого смысла наложенных ограничений) вы хотите добиться? Подозреваю, что того же эффекта вы можете добиться в C# по-другому.

Comment: @VladD ожидаемый эффект, судя по всему - связать двух конкретных наследников Connection и Client в жесткую пару: `SomeClient : Client<SomeConnection>`, `SomeConnection: Connection<SomeClient>`

Comment: @PashaPash: Тогда так: `class Connection<FormalT>`, class `Client<FormalT>`. и считать внутри, что `Connection<X>` должен работать с `Client<X>`, и наоборот.

Comment: @VladD это понятно, но в java это можно сделать без FormalT. Нет в таком решении внутренней красоты! :)

Comment: @PashaPash: На самом деле в решении на Java тоже есть неформализуемое соглашение о том, что работать надо с параметром `T`, а не с произвольным `Client<Z>`. Так что особой разницы нет. Причём решение на Java не сильно скалируется: что если нам нужно связать _три_ класса? С формальным параметром это просто.

Comment: Вот если бы T должно было торчать наружу, как в `List<T>`, был бы смысл. Сейчас, без подробностей, смысл входящего параметра всё равно формальный. (По-моему, так.)

Comment: Что можно почитать по поводу FormalT ?

Answer (score 1):

А если так?

```
public abstract class Client<T, U> where T : IConnection<U>
    {

    }
```